# how to make InputLabelProps focused TextField material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I make this style for TextField InputLabelProps

```
const styles = theme => ({
inputLabel: {
    '&:before': {
        color: themeStyle.textFieldUnderLineColor,
    },
    '&:after': {
        color: themeStyle.tabIndicatorProps,
    },
    '&:hover:before': {
        color: [themeStyle.appBarRDbgk, '!important'],
    },
    color: themeStyle.dialogContentColor,
},})
```

I use it as follows:

```
<TextField InputLabelProps={classes.inputLabel}>    </TextField>
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you need to pass `classes.inputLabel` as `classes` prop to your `InputLabelProps`:

```
<TextField InputLabelProps={{classes: {root: classes.inputLabel}}}>    </TextField>
```